# AWS RDS Param long_query_time set 0 but still no slow_logs

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have configured AWS RDS with the following parameters:

```
join_buffer_size: 67108864
log_queries_not_using_indexes: 1
long_query_time: 0
query_cache_size: 67108864
query_cache_type: 1
slow_query_log: 1
```

Mysqltuner gives the following output:

```
[!!] Slow queries: 98% (764K/772K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 1% (51/5082)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0M/420.5M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 98.1% (41M cached / 789K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 70.2% (381K cached / 543K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (50 temp sorts / 85K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 3023
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 2% (1K on disk / 67K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (51 created / 47K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 25% (1K open / 6K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (1K/65K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 98% (985K immediate / 998K locks)
```

I'm getting very few slow query logs. I think I should be get one for every query. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you looking at the RDS console's slow log file? Or querying against the mysql database's slow_log table? I have a setup similar to yours and my queries are being written into the slow_log table. I'm still trying to figure out how to get them into the log files.

Comment: I figured out how to route to the log file, so if that's the same thing you're experiencing, see the section titled "Accessing the MySQL Slow Query and General Logs" on this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.MySQL.html

Answer (score 0):

- Login to your AWS console and go to RDS.
- From the left menu, select Parameter Groups
- Create a new parameter group for Postgres, by copying the default Postgres parameter group
- Edit the following parameters in the new group:
- Parameter Name                Value
- log_min_duration_statement    250
- log_statement                 none
- log_duration                  0